# Invalid regular expression : Dangling meta character "*"

Tags: java, regex

I am creating an identification window with login and username for JavaFX, and I am using regex to make sure that the password contains at least one special character and one digit.

This is the regular expression I'm using

```java
newValue.matches("*\\d+.*\\W+.*")
```

It works on testing sites online however I am getting and error while I enter any input in the textfield. Here is the segment of code I am using:

```java
public void progressBarHandler() {
    login.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue.matches("*\\d+.*\\W+.*")) {
            passState.textProperty().set("Bad");
        }
        else passState.textProperty().set("Ok");
    });
}
```

Whenever I run the code and I write something in the textfield login I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
```

Comment: You've shared the regex, but no code showing how you apply the regex, nor any examples of input and the actual error message you're getting. Without them, it's hard to help.

Comment: this looks unrelated to fx (nothing special done to the text of a textField) - so best to test failing inputs in a plain main that does nothing but printout hard-coded String values against the regex. Anyway, [mcve] please (as @Grismar already noted)

Comment: The error message is clear enough. The meta-code `*` allows repeating the previous character or group zero or more times – but there is nothing before your first `*`, so what should it repeat?

Comment: You simply forgot a `.` at the start, `newValue.matches(".*\\d+.*\\W+.*")`. However, a better pattern here would be `newValue.matches("\\D*\\d\\w*\\W.*")`

Comment: No, either Thomas' or my solution works for you. They both can't be working for you.

Comment: You are right, sorry my mistake. Finally it is your solution that works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` quantifier "repeats" (quantifies) the pattern it modifies zero or more times in a greedy way (allows the regex engine to "take" (=consume) as many chars as it can with the given pattern). If `*` or any other quantifier appears at the start of a pattern, there is no pattern the quantifier can modify, and the error appears.

That is, `*abc*` glob pattern used as a regex will produce this same issue, as well as `{1,}abc.*`, `+abc.*` or `{5}+abc.*`, etc.

You may fix the pattern by simply adding a dot in front of the `*` here since you expect to match a string that contains a pattern `digits...non-word chars...`:

```java
newValue.matches(".*\\d+.*\\W+.*")
//                ^
```

However, a better, more efficient pattern here would be

```java
newValue.matches("\\D*\\d\\w*\\W.*")
```

It matches

- start of string (`matches` requires a full string match)
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `\d` - a digit
- `\w*` - 0 or more word chars
- `\W` - a non-word char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.
- end of string (`matches` requires a full string match).

Answer (score 3):

In regular expressions, the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) `*` means "*zero or more matches of the preceding character (class) or group*". But in your case, there is nothing preceding, the star is the first character in your regex string. That's what the error indicates.

If you actually want to match an asterisk you have to escape it with backslashs:

```
"\\*\\d+.*\\W+.*"
```

Comment: I just rechecked and it doesn't do what I need it to. It works syntaxically but it doesn't achieve the intended functionality.

Comment: Too bad. Feel free to write up a new question then about that next problem. My answer here only addresses this question. Also note that i wrote `"*If* you actually want to match an asterisk" -- only you could know what your regexp was actually supposed to match. I was just telling you why you got the error message you got (which was your question).